# Powershell,Silent Installation not working

Tags: powershell, installation

Need to install a **sample.msi** file through powershell,i have written command like below

```bsh
msiexec.exe /I c:\fakepath\sample.msi /quiet
```

I am not getting any errors and application is also not installing

Note:Same piece of code is working,when i have tried it in c# code by using PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke(); it is working

I am always getting windows installer prompt (GUI message box).

```
Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.17763.404 
msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]
Install Options
    </package | /i> <Product.msi>
...
```

Comment: Of course you're not getting errors. Remove the /quiet flag... use /quiet only when you know your command works.

Comment: @Nelson, due to the formatting of the question (since fixed), the error was obscured; it suggests that `msiexec` refuses invocation altogether, due to invalid command-line syntax.

Comment: @RaviKumar The `msiexec` command line shown is _syntactically_ correct, so it wouldn't produce the symptom you describe. Please show the _actual_ command line (or at least one that reproduces the symptom).

Comment: Highly recommend copying the exact command line. Spaces in file paths is typically the #1 cause of the problem.